# Python Counter from txt file

Tags: python, text-files, counter

I would like to init a collections.Counter object from a text file of word frequency counts. That is, I have a file "counts.txt":

```
rank  wordform         abs     r        mod
   1  the           225300    29   223066.9
   2  and           157486    29   156214.4
   3  to            134478    29   134044.8
...
 999  fallen           345    29      326.6
1000  supper           368    27      325.8
```

I would like a Counter object `wordCounts` such that I can call

```
>>> print wordCounts.most_common(3)
[('the', 225300), ('of', 157486), ('and', 134478)]
```

What is the most efficient, Pythonic way

Comment: Are the fields in the file separated by tabs, comma, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two versions. The first takes your `counts.txt` as a regular text file. The second treats it as a csv file (which is what it kind of looks like).

```
from collections import Counter

with open('counts.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip().split() for line in f]
    wordCounts = Counter({line[1]: int(line[2]) for line in lines[1:]})
    print wordCounts.most_common(3)
```

If your data file some how turned out to be delimited by some consistent character or string you could use a `csv.DictReader` object to parse the file.

Shown below is how it could be done **IF** your file were `TAB` delimited.

The data file (as edited by me to be TAB delimited)

```
rank    wordform    abs r   mod
1   the 225300  29  223066.9
2   and 157486  29  156214.4
3   to  134478  29  134044.8
999 fallen  345 29  326.6
1000    supper  368 27  325.8
```

The code

```
from csv import DictReader
from collections import Counter

with open('counts.txt') as f:
    reader = DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
    wordCounts = Counter({row['wordform']: int(row['abs']) for row in reader})
    print wordCounts.most_common(3)
```

Comment: Good sol'n, but I would call `print wordCounts.most_common(3)` after closing the file :)

Comment: All you need to do in that case is un-indent the last line.

Answer (score 2):

```
import collections.Counter

words = dict()
fp = open('counts.txt')

for line in fp:
   items = line.split()
   words[items[1].strip()] = int(items[2].strip())

wordCounts = collections.Counter(words)
```

Comment: I like this a lot; clean and simple. But I accepted @PaulRooney's answer because he handles the file better using `with open()`.

Comment: @alavin89 - yep his answer is more Pythonic