# Count how many times each address appear in data file using python

Tags: python, frequency

I'd like to count how many times each address appear in the data file using python.
Address range is not fixed which means that address range is different from each data files.
Some address between min and max are not appear at all.
(2nd column is address.)

To solve this efficiently, how can I approach?
I didn't know which data structure would be OK and which function will help to it?

I just tried to use large array which index means address. Read the data file and plus 1 to array[address]. This is poor code.

Added : 
I tried to pieces_write[1].value_counts(), the results is

```
 print(pieces_write[1].value_counts())
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

Example of DATA FILE  ( 2nd column is address)

```
 0       303567       3584       Write       0.000000
 1       55590       3072       Write       0.000000
 0       303574       3584       Write       0.026214
 1       240840       3072       Write       0.026214
 1       55596       3072       Read       0.078643
 0       303581       3584       Write       0.117964
 1       55596       3072       Write       0.117964
 0       303588       3584       Write       0.530841
 1       55596       3072       Write       0.530841
 0       303595       3584       Write       0.550502
 1       240840       3072       Write       0.550502
 1       55602       3072       Read       0.602931
 0       303602       3584       Write       0.648806
 1       55602       3072       Write       0.648806
 0       303609       3584       Write       0.910950
 1       55602       3072       Write       0.910950
 0       303616       3584       Write       0.930611
 1       240840       3072       Write       0.930611
 1       55608       3072       Read       0.983040
 0       303623       3584       Write       1.028915
 1       55608       3072       Write       1.028915
 0       303630       3584       Write       1.330380
 1       55608       3072       Write       1.330380
```

CODE for Data file read

```
for line in open(datafile):
    line_data = line.split()
    if int(line_data[1]) < 6000000:
        if line_data[3] == 'Read':
            pieces_read.append(line_data)
            x_read.append(count)
        else:
            pieces_write.append(line_data)
            x_write.append(count)
        x_tot.append(count) 
        pieces_tot.append(line_data)
        count += 1
```

Comment: What have you tried already to implement? Are there any specific problems with the code?

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: @yeputons I add more description.

Comment: @WKK even if you have "poor code", please show it and point out what exactly did not work. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (if it's relevant)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496414/python-counter-from-txt-file this seems to be it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`collections.Counter`:](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter 

words = []

for line in open('data.txt'):
  # Your logic here
  words.append(line.split()[1])

words_dict = Counter(words)

for key, value in words_dict.items():
  print(key, value)
```

**Output:**

```
303574 1
55596 3
303630 1
303567 1
303595 1
303616 1
240840 3
303588 1
55590 1
303623 1
303602 1
303581 1
55608 3
303609 1
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do it with pandas like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Data_File_Path', sep='\s+', header=None, usecols=[1])
df[ df[1] < 6000000 ][1].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
55608     3
55602     3
55596     3
240840    3
303581    1
303609    1
303574    1
303567    1
303630    1
303595    1
303623    1
55590     1
303588    1
303602    1
303616    1
Name: 1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @WKK do you want to put down the counts in a file?