# Need to find the most frequent character (A...Z) in the file

Tags: python

**Task:**

> You have a file containing n numbers (n does not exceed 10^6 numbers).
> You need to determine the most frequent character in the file and
> output it and how many times it appeared in the file.

**My problem:**

My program outputs the 4 most frequent characters in the file, although only the most frequent character needs to be output.

The implementation of my solution is shown below.

Can you please tell me what I am not taking into account in my decision?

```py
with open("24.txt") as f:
    st = f.read()

    array = [0] * 26
    
    for x in st:
        a[ord(x) - ord("A")] += 1
    
    Max = 0
    i_max = 0
    
    for i in range(26):
        if a[i] > Max:
            Max = a[i]
            i_max = i
    
    simb = chr(i_max + ord("A"))
    print(simb, Max)
```

Comment: Please improve your question: What you tried so far etc.?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496414/python-counter-from-txt-file I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @droebi i have no idea how to do this.

Comment: @mozway   letter, count = c.most_common(1)[0]
NameError: name 'c' is not defined

Comment: @Rendivy I'm afraid Stack Overflow can't help you then - even if a solution is provided, it won't help you on your way, you'll come back with the next problem in the same way. You need to learn how to think like a programmer, that's not something that can be taught in a single answer. If you have a specific technical issue (for example: why is my counter off by one? or something like that), it's something we could help with...

Comment: @Rendivy that was a typo

Comment: @Rendivy In this case, you'd need to break down this problem to several smaller problems, and each of them can be broken down to even smaller ones, etc. - At a high level, you'd need to 1) prepare an appropriate data structure to map characters A-Z to their counts (initially zero), 2) read the file contents, 3) iterate over the characters, 4) for each character, increase the corresponding counter in your data structure, 5) loop over all the counters for A-Z, 6) print the letter and its count for each entry. You need to come up with this sort of plan in your head and then continue.

Comment: @CherryDT I have many more similar tasks where I need to find the minimum value. Thank you for your advice. I'll try to solve it myself: D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is straightforward with `collections.Counter`

#### printing all characters:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    counts = Counter(f.read())

print('\n'.join(f'letter "{letter}": {count}' for letter, count in counts.items()
                if letter != '\n'))
```

example output:

```
letter "A": 5
letter "B": 6
letter "C": 1
```

#### printing the most common:

```
from collections import Counter

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    counts = Counter(f.read())

letter, count = counts.most_common(1)[0]
print(f'letter "{letter}": {count}')
```

example output:

```
letter "X": 54
```

#### note on removing unwanted characters:

you can delete the unwanted key(s) (O(1) operation) prior to using the `counts`:

```
del counts[' ']
del counts['\n']
```

Comment: Nice answer but if there are spaces in text it counts them, so if you want not to count them just add `.replace(" ", "")` to the output text before Counter() function.

Comment: @mignaway better, do `counts[' '] = -1` or `del c[' ']`, thus the operation is `O(1)`, I updated the answer

Comment: @mozway big thanks man, I'm new to python, and never used the collections library. but I understood the course of the decision. now I will go get acquainted with the library to fully understand

Comment: @mozway you're right...just remove the space element count from the list instead of removing all space on string..i didn't even think of that lul <3

Comment: @Rendivy python is "included with batteries", there are many core modules with awesome functions, check the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) documentation ;)